# Automating complex tasks with http requests?

Tags: http, httprequest

I need to automate a long list of tasks using post requests.
I need to make a payment, and I want to use only http requests.
I cannot use headless browsers or anything that actively interacts with a browser, so please do not suggest that. I will use JSoup. (Why? I need to run multiple tasks, and headless browsers are too heavy).

The website has different steps to accomplish the task. The problem here is that the website sends a lot of different gibberish requests to various websites, and I have no idea on what I can manipulate/need to send.

For example, by using firefox's built in network tool, I can clearly see that there are a lot of different cookies, and those cookies actually change every time another request is sent.

Example:

Task on page 1:

> Request cookie: cookievalue1
>
> Response cookie: cookievalue1

Task on page 2:

> Request cookie: cookievalue2
>
> Response cookie: cookievalue2

Where does the browser get the cookie on task 2? Why does the server respond with the same cookie?

How should I automate this task? I have no idea even where to start.
Are there some specific things that I need to look out for?

Comment: @ᴇʟᴇvᴀтᴇ Too heavy, I need to run multiple tasks (up to 30-40), I already benchmarked most headless browsers and I can run only 10 tasks max of them.

Comment: @ᴇʟᴇvᴀтᴇ I know that, I am using JSoup. That is not the question that I am asking though.